# Uniqueness of entropy solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives, hyperbolic-equations

I am starting to study hyperbolic equations of conservation laws. I have read that there exists a unique entropy solution of the problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u_t+f(u)_x=0~,~~(x,t)\in\mathbb{R}\times(0,\infty)\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x)~,~~x\in\mathbb{R}
\end{array}\right.
$$
and it satisfies, for example:
$$
\left|\left|u(\cdot,t)\right|\right|_{L_1}\le\left|\left|u_0\right|\right|_{L_1}~~\forall t>0.
$$
I think that a function equal a.e. to an entropy solution is also an entropy solution, is it right? Then, how is it possible to obtain the previous bound if the line $\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ is a null space in the domain?